# How to package and install Node js application in remote Machine

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, package

I am developing the node js application in my Ubuntu local machine. I want to package my application and run in any remote Ubuntu machine and start it.

Doing the following in my local environment:-

1. Installing npm packages in my local machine like **"npm install express --save"**
2. All Node packages are saved under myProject/node_modules and reference of package are stored in package.json
3. Make myProject folder a myProject.zip includes myProject/node_modules
4. Store myProject.zip in storage

Doing the following in my Remote environment:-

1. Install Node Js and npm

> ```
> sudo apt-get -y update
> sudo apt-get -y install build-essential libssl-dev
> curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | sudo -E bash -
> sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
> ```

2. Download myProject.zip from storage
3. unzip myProject.zip
4. cd myProject
5. As I want to start my application as a service, I am installing this package using **"npm install -g forever-service --save"**
6. forever-service install myapp --script server.js
7. service myapp start

I want to know whether my above approach is correct regarding the following:-

1. Unpacking and starting the node js application in Remote machine
2. Especially installing the package. In my local environment (locally), I am using **"npm install express --save"** and **"npm install -g forever-service --save"** in remote machine (globally with -g option)
3. If I do **"npm install -g forever-service --save"** in my local environment and package myProject as zip. It won't be available in myProject.zip as forever-service is installed globally.

Now I am trying to install azure-cli package. Whether it should be install locally or globally.

Comment: I think, you should not zip application dependencies. Just create zip of your application(excluding dependencies), copy it to remote server, unpack it, then install the dependencies(provided you have internet connection) and then run it.

Comment: All node packages should be installed globally or locally in remote machine.

Comment: I always install them locally from `package.json`.

Comment: [forever-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever-service) doesn't work If i install it without -g option in remote machine

Comment: Yes, that service needs to be install globally. https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever-service#prerequisite

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge, I am using my application by accessing and working on it remotely by using the `ssh services` on Ubuntu. 
You need to install the ssh service using `sudo apt install openssh-server` command. After installing the same follow below steps:

- Open the terminal and make sure that you have admin privileges to work around.
- Then type `ssh userName@IPadress-of-remote-machine` command and hit enter.

Next, it will ask you for authentication password of remote machine that you want to access.

And there you go after successful authentication with the terminal access of remote machine and can access your application directory as needed.

Here are the great docs regarding ssh usage:
https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openssh-server.html

You can refer to docs below for more clarification.
http://linux-sys-adm.com/how-to-install-and-configure-ssh-on-ubuntu-server-14.04-lts-step-by-step/

Hope this is helpful for you!